# Unable to targeting my project to .NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, sdk, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a new project with .NET core 5.0 with no luck.

I downloaded VS 2019, dotnet 5.0 sdk (Also Runtime), restarted my computer twice.
But still I don't have the new framework in this list:

[image]

What Am I missing?

Comment: .net 5 is .net core project not classic .net framework . You also need the 16.8 preview version to use .net 5 RC2

Comment: What do you mean by 16.8 preview version?

Comment: current VS2019 is at version 16.7.x and preview version is 16.8: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/. Read about requirements in this blogpost: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-rc-2/

Comment: Great thanks that was helpful